# Undo "sudo google-chrome --no-sandbox"

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

In order to fix some other unrelated issue I wanted to run chrome as sudo. The Terminal output told me to run the above-mentioned command. Besides that not being helpful I get an error "Cannot open profile" and some other things each time I open chrome, even via the graphical icon or a plain google-chrome in the terminal. How can I reverse this?

Comment: I should add that the layout now looks somewhat different and chrome also does not load my extensions or starting page, but can read my history

Comment: See [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications) - your chrome profile has likely become owned by root and you will need to `chown` it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications) @steeldriver linked (in comments) I found the solution:

> Assuming there are no files in your home directory that you want to be owned by any other user or that you want to have any other group membership (for sharing), you can run:
>
> ```
> sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~
> ```
>
> If you have any files where you need to preserve the group owner, you can run
>
> ```
> sudo chown -R $USER ~
> ```

Credits - (user [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan))

I didn't need the latter, but now everything is fine again.